# Compare 2 csv's and output the row differences to seperate files

Tags: powershell, csv, join, merge, output

**i have a 1.csv**

name,surname,height,city,county,state,zipCode

John,Doe,120,jefferson,Riverside,NJ,8075

Jack,Yan,220,Phila,Riverside,PA,9119

Jill,Fan,120,jefferson,Riverside,NJ,8075

Steve,Tan,220,Phila,Riverside,PA,9119

Alpha,Fan,120,jefferson,Riverside,NJ,8075

Bloggs,Joe,7,Washington,WA.1285

**and a 2.csv**

name,surname,height,city,county,state,zipCode

John,Doe,120,jefferson,Riverside,NJ,8075

Jack,Yan,220,Phila,Riverside,PA,9119

Jill,Fan,120,jefferson,Riverside,NJ,8075

Steve,Tan,220,Phila,Riverside,PA,9119

Bravo,Tan,220,Phila,Riverside,PA,9119

I want to compare the rows of both 1.csv and 2.csv files and output the rows that meet the below criteria

**if exist in 1.csv and 2.csv then output to Output1.csv**

**if exist in 2.csv and does not exist in 1.csv output to Output1.csv**

**if exist in 1.csv and does not exist in 2.csv output to Output2.csv**

*so Output1.csv should be*

John,Doe,120,jefferson,Riverside,NJ,8075

Jack,Yan,220,Phila,Riverside,PA,9119

Jill,Fan,120,jefferson,Riverside,NJ,8075

Steve,Tan,220,Phila,Riverside,PA,9119

Bravo,Tan,220,Phila,Riverside,PA,9119

*and Output2.csv should be*

Bloggs,Joe,7,Washington,WA.1285

Most of the similar questions only output to one file and i need 2 outputs. Is this possible?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `Compare-Object` to compare the two collections, then use the intrinsic `.Where()` extension method to split the results into two based on whether the entry was only found in `a.csv` or not:

```
$a = Import-Csv path\to\a.csv
$b = Import-Csv path\to\b.csv

$outputs = @(
  # compare the two files, output everything, then split based on side-indicator
  Compare-Object $a $b -IncludeEqual
).Where({$_.SideIndicator -ne '<='}, 'Split')

# first collection will be the ones that satisfied `{$_.SideIndicator -ne '<='}`
$outputs[0] |ForEach-Object InputObject |Export-Csv output1.csv -NoTypeInformation
# second collection will be the ones that didn't, eg. the ones only found in a.csv
$outputs[1] |ForEach-Object InputObject |Export-Csv output2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want to output to 3 different files, I'd suggest grouping on the side indicator with `Group-Object`:

```
Compare-Object $a $b -IncludeEqual |Group-Object SideIndicator |ForEach-Object {
  # determine name of output file based on indicator
  $outputNames = @{'<='='a_only.csv';'=='='both.csv';'=>'='b_only.csv'}
  $outputName = $outputNames[$_.Group[0].SideIndicator]

  $_.Group |ForEach-Object InputObject |Export-Csv $outputName -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: many thanks for the quick answer, im completely new to PS and im not sure which parameters i need to ammend. i've changed the path to to my csv's but i get the below error:At line:6 char:1
+ ).Where({$_.SideIndicator -ne '<='}, 'Split')
+ ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: @rialnet There was a typo (which I've fixed now), but it doesn't really explain the specific error your received. Are you by any chance using PowerShell 2.0 or 3.0 (Windows 7/2008R2 or Windows 8/2012)?

Comment: it must have been your typo as its running now!

Comment: @rialnet That's great! If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark outlined on the left :)

Comment: ok so i have a single output1 file, but i really need 2 output files - each will contain a unique data set (according to the critera i need meeting) from the original csv's

Comment: Another typo, meant to output the second collection to `output2.csv` instead. fixed now

Comment: i guessed as much - running again with the ammendment!

Comment: would it also be possible to have a 3rd output? if exist in 2.csv and does not exist in 1.csv output to Output3.csv

Comment: @rialnet I've updated the answer to show how you can do that

Comment: Export-Csv : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Path'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:8 char:52
+ ...  $_.Group |ForEach-Object InputObject |Export-Csv $outputName -NoType ...
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: `$outputNames[$_.Group]` should have been `$outputNames[$_.Group[0].SideIndicator]`, try again

Comment: both.csv
Export-Csv : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Path'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:8 char:52
+ ...  $_.Group |ForEach-Object InputObject |Export-Csv $outputName -NoType ...
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: a_only.csv
Export-Csv : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Path'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:8 char:52
+ ...  $_.Group |ForEach-Object InputObject |Export-Csv $outputName -NoType ...
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand

Comment: its puting a wavy line in the error under $outputname

Comment: should it be $outputnames?

Comment: i changed the above to $outputnames and the script appeared to run, however once the script completes in the PS window i get 'both.csv' and 'a_only.csv' (no b_only.csv) but no output files